# Deal with large number

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

I'm having a problem in a RSA challenge. I already had p, and q is calculated based on p.

```
(100000000**(p-1) -1)%p
```

q is the nearest prime to this number.

I knew that my comp will take a huge time too compute this (Don't know what time it would take). So can you guys suggest some ways to deal with this large number. Many thanks!

Comment: fermat's little theorem